# How to build query as variable (from user Input) in prisma.queryRaw without using queryRawUnsafe

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma, resolver

I was trying to query my (postgres) db with a customizable statement built front end.
My resolver gets the built query inside the input param, but when I use the queryRaw method I get this error:

```
`"\nInvalid `prisma.queryRaw()` invocation:\n\n\n  Raw query failed. Code: `42601`. Message: `db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"$1\"`"`
```

Is there a way to build a custom query and pass it like the input variable WITHOUT USING queryRawUnsafe to prisma? (queryRawUnsafe works fine, but well.. it's unsafe XD) Thanks <3

Here is my code.

```
  getCars: (_parent, { input }, { prisma }) => {
    if(input){

        console.log(input) // --> SELECT * FROM car WHERE car."plate" ILIKE '%123%'  //type String
        const differentInput = '%123%'

        // const result =  prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM car WHERE car."plate" ILIKE '%123%'` // works
        // const result =  prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM car WHERE car."plate" ILIKE ${differentInput}` // works
        // const result =  prisma.$queryRawUnsafe(input) // works

        const result =  prisma.$queryRaw`${input}` // Doesn`t work
        return result

    }
    // ... Other code
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`prisma.$queryRaw` only accepts templated strings, not just strings. You can use the `Prisma.sql` helper to generate those templated strings to get the expected results. That might look like:

```
const sql = Prisma.sql`SELECT * FROM car WHERE car."plate" ILIKE '%123%'`
const result =  prisma.$queryRaw`${sql}`
```

The [queryRaw documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) mentions `Prisma.sql` with other examples but doesn't show any examples of what you are trying to do.